# Indexing list of data.frames – how to get all x-th columns?

Tags: r, indexing

I have list of data.frames and I wonder whether there is an easy indexing way of getting all third columns of all data.frames. Or all columns named x?
Speaking R:

```
lapply(names(mylist),function(x) mylist[[x]][,3])
```

Is there any way to do it by just indexing, like mylist[[]][,3]? (which does not work obviously)

EDIT: And how do you do that, when you want to use a function like nlevels in that, like

```
  lapply(names(mylist),function(x) nlevels(mylist[[x]][,3]))
```

given that column 3 is a factor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe this is somewhat easier:

```
lapply(mylist, "[[", 3)
lapply(mylist, "[[", name_of_column)
```

Comment: +1 indeed. did not know you could use the second argument of lapply like that. slick. But on the other hand that means there's no way using mere indexing?

Comment: What do you mean by "mere indexing"?

Comment: mylist[[]][,3], something like this if it would work. Without using any looping or applying.